# Programming in Swift on Linux

Tags: swift, linux, swift3, atom-editor

I would like to prepare the *environment* for working with **Swift** on **Ubuntu 16.04**.

I installed [Swift](https://swift.org/download/) and [Atom](https://atom.io) editor.
I installed the *Script* package, which allows me to run code from the Atom editor.

Generally it is nice when I compile and run one file (*Ctrl+Shift+B* shortcut).
The problem is when I would like to build a project composed of several files.
Classes defined in the other files (not the one I compile) are not visible (compilation error).

Is it possible to configure the editor to compile and run the entire project?
How to import external library, eg *ObjectMapper* ?

Comment: FYI: [Medium: Hacking Atom to create a Swift IDE that runs on Linux and Mac ⇗](https://medium.com/@Aciid/hacking-atom-to-create-a-swift-ide-that-runs-on-linux-and-mac-c7d9520a0fac), [Medium: Getting started with Vapor and Swift On Ubuntu 16.04 ⇗](https://medium.com/@addamb/getting-started-with-vapor-and-swift-on-ubuntu-16-04-31a426654115), [Medium/TheSwiftWebDeveloper: Using Atom for Web Development with Swift ⇗](https://theswiftwebdeveloper.com/using-atom-for-web-development-with-swift-6ab42ac415c2)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Atom package [build](https://atom.io/packages/build). It allows you to create custom build commands and such by using common build providers. You can build with a Makefile or JSON or CSON or YAML or even Javascript. It provides enough flexibility that you can build just about anything. Just make your build file so that it points to all the files to build with the right compiler (probably `swiftc` in your case). With a Javascript build file, you can even specify a command to run before and after the build, say, to run your newly built program.

Answer (score 1):

There's a great open source project I have been watching called Marathon. It's a package manager and they have been Working on a deployment on linux. I'm not sure how much success they have had, but you can follow along here and maybe help out.

https://github.com/JohnSundell/Marathon/issues/37

Edit: It looks like it does work on linux!

```
git clone https://github.com/JohnSundell/Marathon.git
$ cd Marathon
$ swift build -c release
$ cp -f .build/release/Marathon /usr/local/bin/marathon
```

Answer (score 1):

For dependencies, you should use Swift Package Manager.

You can check how Vapor is built - it is prepared for build apps for Ubuntu too.

Also, Vapor toolbox would help you with other projects
https://docs.vapor.codes/2.0/getting-started/install-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 1):

You can build a Swift project using VS Code + [Swift Development Environment extension](https://github.com/vknabel/vscode-swift-development-environment)

If steps on the link above are not clear enough, I've put more details in a [blog post](http://mijocoder.blogspot.com/2018/09/swift-development-journey-on-linux.html)